# Sum vector with corresponding name

Tags: r, vector, sum

Let say you have a list of vector:

```
L = list()
L[[1]]= c(2,34,6,7,3)
L[[2]]= c(3,4,6,8,1)
names(L[[1]])=c("A","B","C","D","E")
names(L[[2]])=c("A","R","C","D","F")
L

## [[1]]
##  A  B  C  D  E 
##  2 34  6  7  3 
## 
## [[2]]
## A R C D F 
## 3 4 6 8 1
```

And I want to sum the 2 vectors by the name of each element... Results:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  R
5 34 12 15  3  1  4
```

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another solution using `tapply`

```
> tapply(unlist(L), names(unlist(L)), sum)
 A  B  C  D  E  F  R 
 5 34 12 15  3  1  4
```

*EDIT*

It will work even if your vectors have different lengths, see the example:

```
> L = list()
> L[[1]]= 1:10
> L[[2]]= c(3,4,6,8,1)
> names(L[[1]])=LETTERS[1:10]
> names(L[[2]])=c("A","R","C","D","F")

> tapply(unlist(L), names(unlist(L)), sum)
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  R 
 4  2  9 12  5  7  7  8  9 10  4  # IT WORKS!!!
```

Comment: I like this better than mine.

Comment: Thanks it works for now... but what if my vectors are not the same length, it won't work

Comment: @joellapalme Either answer works if they are not the same length.

Answer (score 2):

```
 x <- aggregate(unlist(L), by=list(names(unlist(L))), FUN=sum)
result <- x$x
names(result) <- x$Group.1
result
## A  B  C  D  E  F  R 
## 5 34 12 15  3  1  4
```

Comment: Thanks it works for now... but what if my vectors are not the same length, it won't work.